# Merging two lists of the same type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have 2 lists with objects of the same type:

```
[{"id":1, "val": "A"}, {"id":2, val:"B"}]
```

and

```
[{"id":2, "val": "C"}, {"id":3, val:"D"}]
```

I need to merge list 2 to list 1 in a specific way: alter the existing object in 1 with new value of the object with the same id from 2 if exists.

For this example result should be like this:

```
[{"id":1, "val": "A"}, {"id":2, val:"C"}]
```

Is there any efficient and intelligent way to handle it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    data class Obj(val id: Int, val value: String)
    val first = listOf(Obj(1, "A"), Obj(2, "B"))
    val second = listOf(Obj(2, "C"), Obj(3, "D"))
    val buf = second.associateBy { it.id }
    val result = first.map { buf[it.id] ?: it }
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Replace `groupBy` with `associateBy` and your solution will work properly ;-)